# Codeigniter. How to pass parameters $ _GET in the route.php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

This code **$route['basketball'] = "controller/product/?id=7"** does not work.

```
function product()
{
    echo $_GET['id']  // no output
}
```

How to describe the rules in the route?

Comment: I guess this is not GET, but POST request, so check the output of `echo $_POST['id'];`

Answer (score 2):

If possible use CodeIgniter's standard URL routes.
In your case:

```
$route['basketball'] = "controller/product/7";

function product()
{

}
```

OR if $_GET['id'] needs to be dynamic

```
$route['basketball/:num'] = "controller/product";

function product($id)
{

}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are in PHP , you can basically set $_GET and $_REQUEST parameters which are super global variables that can be accessed anywhere in the code.
So you can do a callback and set them there.

For example:

```
$route['basketball'] = function(){
  $_GET['id']=$_REQUEST['id'] = 7;
  return "controller/product/";

};
```

Then in your code you can access $_GET['id'] or whatever.