# Codeigniter Routing issue with get parameters

Tags: codeigniter-3

I want to give route url with get parameters to static url like below

From "/web/view?id=10"  To  /about

Similarly "/web/view?id=11"  To  /contact

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot provide routes based on get parameters in CodeIgniter. The best way to handle this is route /web/view to one method which then goes to /about and /contact based on `$this->input->get('id');` See [Codeigniter. How to pass parameters $ _GET in the route.php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749616/codeigniter-how-to-pass-parameters-get-in-the-route-php) for more info